# Trying to 'map' nested JSON element object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I am trying to 'map' nested JSON elements that have objects in order to build HTML. I am not sure what I am doing wrong with the syntax as follows:

```
    array1 = [
      {
        "name":"test",
        "things": [
          { "name":"thing1" },
          { "name": "thing2"}
        ]
      }
    ];

    const createThingy = (item) => `
        <p>${item.name}</p>
    `

    // pass a function to map
    const map1 = array1.things.map(createThingy).join('');
    console.log(array1);

    // expected output: <p>thing1</p><p>thing2</p>
```

Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: `array1` is an array so it doesn't have a `things` property, you'll need to loop over your array to access the inner objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the array as an object. It's accessed in a similar way, so if it were an object it would be like this:

```
let array1 = {
  0: {
    "name":"test",
    "things": [
      { "name": "thing1" },
      { "name": "thing2" }
    ]
  }
};
```

Therefore, to access its first element directly you need:

```
array1[0].things
```

To get your desired outcome you need to the following:

```js
let array1 = [
  {
    "name": "test",
    "things": [
      { "name": "thing1" },
      { "name": "thing2" }
    ]
  }
];

const createThingy = (item) => `
  <p>${item.name}</p>
`;

// pass a function to map
const map1 = array1[0].things.map(createThingy).join('');
console.log(map1);
```

In case your array can have multiple elements, you can use the following:

```js
let array1 = [
  {
    "name": "test",
    "things": [
      { "name": "thing1" },
      { "name": "thing2" }
    ]
  }
];

const createThingy = (item) => `
  <p>${item.name}</p>
`;

// pass a function to map
const map1 = array1.reduce((acc, elem) => acc + elem.things.map(createThingy).join(''), "");
console.log(map1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   array1 = [
      {
        "name":"test",
        "things": [
          { "name":"thing1" },
          { "name": "thing2"}
        ]
      }
    ];

    const createThingy = (item) => `
        <p>${item.name}</p>
    `

    // pass a function to map
    const map1 = array1[0].things.map(createThingy).join('');
    console.log(array1);
    console.log(map1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nick Parsons said, you have to loop over the `array1` array to get `things` property.

```
const array1 = [
  {
    "name":"test",
    "things": [
      { "name":"thing1" },
      { "name": "thing2"}
    ]
  }
];

const createThingy = (item) => `
    <p>${item.name}</p>
`

// pass a function to map
const map1 = array1[0].things.map(createThingy).join('');

console.log(array1);
console.log(map1);
```

Also, be advised that if your `array1` variable is empty or in case there is no `things` attribute in preferred index, your code code will give error. Be sure to check if they are empty. You can do this by using lodash `isEmpty` function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over the array1 to get the desired output as Nick Parsons said in the comments.

```
array1 = [
      {
        "name":"test",
        "things": [
          { "name":"thing1" },
          { "name": "thing2"}
        ]
      }
    ];

    const createThingy = (item) => `
        <p>${item.name}</p>
    `

array1.map(item => {
item.map(key => createThingy(key).join(''));
});

    // expected output: <p>thing1</p><p>thing2</p>
```